# How do you display shape result from module to page on orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to module creation and I  created an mvc app that is getting data from another source other than the orchard database. I turned it into a module to where I just have a controller and view what I am trying to do is display that view into different zones. Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display a view from a controller it is chucked into the content zone. If you want to display data in different zones you will most likely want to use [widgets](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-widget). However, you can dispatch an arbitrary shape to a zone from, well anywhere in Orchard really. This would add a shape called *MyShape* to the *AsideFirst* zone.

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _workContextAccessor;
    private readonly IOrchardServices _orchardServices;

    public MyController(IOrchardServices orchardServices, IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor) {
        _workContextAccessor = workContextAccessor;
        _orchardServices = orchardServices;
    }

    public ActionResult Random() {
        var shape = _orchardServices.New.MyShape();
        var zone = "AsideFirst";
        var position = "2";

        _workContextAccessor.GetContext().Layout.Zones[zone].Add(shape, position);

        return View("MainView");
    }
}
```

I don't really know what your scenario is but I would say your best bet is probably to look at Orchard Widgets.

Comment: Thank you! just wahat i was looking for